# Categorical variable to denote index of repeated observation in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have the following data frame:

```
> data
v1 v2
1  1
1  1
3  2
4  4
4  4
4  4
6  5
7  6
```

I want to create a categorical variable that denotes the number of repeated occurrences. If an observations is not repeated, then the variable would be 1. If the observations appears twice, then the variable would be 1 for the first occurrence and 2 for the second occurrence. Thus, I want a variable that returns the following data frame:

```
> data_final
v1 v2 dup
1  1  1
1  1  2
3  2  1
4  4  1
4  4  2
4  4  3
6  5  1
7  6  1
```

I have done quite a bit of research in R packages, but I can't find anything that addresses this problem directly. I am doing simulations with very large datasets, so I am hoping to find a function that is not very computationally expensive. Any help would be appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: Use `ave` to count occurrences along unique pairs of `v1` and `v2`: `ave(1:NROW(matrix), matrix$v1, matrix$v2, FUN = seq_along)`

Comment: @lmo I was going to use a matrix, but it seems that it will be easier if I use a data frame. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your dataset is of class `matrix` and not `data.frame`?
It would make things easier if it were a df, but the first example will be with a matrix. Note however that I'm only considering duplicates in the first column. More on this later.

```
result <- lapply(split(mat[, 1], mat[, 1]), seq_along)
result <- cbind(mat, unlist(result))
colnames(result) <- c(colnames(result)[1:2], "dup")
rownames(result) <- NULL
result
     v1 v2 dup
[1,]  1  1   1
[2,]  1  1   2
[3,]  3  2   1
[4,]  4  4   1
[5,]  4  4   2
[6,]  4  4   3
[7,]  6  5   1
[8,]  7  6   1
```

If you have a `data.frame`, named `mydf`, it's much simpler.

```
mydf$dup <- unlist(lapply(split(mydf, mydf[, 1]), function(x) seq_len(nrow(x))))
mydf
  v1 v2 dup
1  1  1   1
2  1  1   2
3  3  2   1
4  4  4   1
5  4  4   2
6  4  4   3
7  6  5   1
8  7  6   1
```

Finally, if you really need a `matrix`, and want to get the duplicates of both columns, transform it first into a df, `mydf <- as.data.frame(matrix)`, and use the code above. Then return to matrix with `as.matrix`.

P.S. `matrix` is a bad name for a matrix, since it already is the name of an `R` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was going to use a matrix, but it seems that it will be easier if I use a data frame. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `dplyr` ,I think you assign name "matrix" to a `data.frame`

```
df%>%group_by(v1,v2)%>%dplyr::mutate(dup=row_number())


# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   v1, v2 [5]
     v1    v2   dup
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     1     1     2
3     3     2     1
4     4     4     1
5     4     4     2
6     4     4     3
7     6     5     1
8     7     6     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was going to use a matrix, but it seems that it will be easier if I use a data frame. I have updated my question